# Recoger valor de Gtk Dialog con Python

Tags: python, ubuntu

Veréis, estoy haciendo un indicador para Ubuntu y quería implementar una ventana de Preferencias. Puesto que no tengo idea de Python, tras bastante esfuerzo y mucha lectura de documentación he conseguido crear una pequeña ventana tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo correcto. Ahora he conseguido recibir los valores del switch y mostrarlos por consola como "on" y "off".

Aquí llega mi problema, que **no sé definir**. Esto es lo que tengo de código.

```
def __init__(self):
    [...]
    label11 = Gtk.Label('Autoarranque:')
    label11.set_alignment(0, 0.5)
    table11.attach(label11, 0, 1, 0, 1, xpadding=5, ypadding=5)
    self.switch1 = Gtk.Switch()
    self.switch1.connect("notify::active", self.on_switch_activated)
    self.switch1.set_active = True
    table11.attach(self.switch1, 1, 2, 0, 1,
                   xpadding=5,
                   ypadding=5,
                   xoptions=Gtk.AttachOptions.SHRINK)
    [...]

def on_switch_activated(self, switch1, gparam):
    if switch1.get_active():
        state = "on"
        return state
    else:
        state = "off"
        return state
    print("Switch ", state)

def close_ok(self):
    stat = on_switch_activated(self, switch1, gparam)
print(stat)
```

Pues al lanzar esto me devuelve un error dentro del `close_ok` que dice `NameError: global name 'on_switch_activated' is not defined`. ¿No se supone que está definido? Si alguien me lo puede explicar se lo agradecería.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Hola, Viral. Este código tiene pinta de ser métodos de una *clase*. Añade la definición de clase para que tenga el sentido completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que parece que te pasa es que `on_switch_activated` es un método, no una función global (falta la definición de clase). El acceso a los método y atributos se ha de realizar a través de la instancia, que normalmente se pasa como argumento llamado `self`:

```
def close_ok(self):
    stat = self.on_switch_activated(self.switch1, self.gparam)
    print(stat)
```

Desconozco si `gparam` era o no atributo de la instancia.

Comment: Todo correcto. Ahora al pulsar `Aceptar` ya retorna un valor como debería. ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Muy bien. Deberías editar el código que has puesto en la pregunta para que quedase que se trataba de métodos en una clase.